# plot robot's route and its orientation along with its control signal

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot my robot route and its orientation along with its control signal with subplots. However, when I run the code robot's orientation and control signal are in the same plot

```
    def plot_arrow(x, y, yaw, length=1.0, width=0.5, fc="r", ec="k"):
if not isinstance(x, float):
    for ix, iy, iyaw in zip(x, y, yaw):
        plot_arrow(ix, iy, iyaw)
else:
    plt.arrow(x, y, length * cos(yaw), length * sin(yaw),
              fc=fc, ec=ec, head_width=width, head_length=width)
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

if show_animation:

```
    plt.cla()
    # for stopping simulation with the esc key.
    plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event',
        lambda event: [exit(0) if event.key == 'escape' else None])
        
    plot_arrow(robot_pose_i[0], robot_pose_i[1], robot_pose_i[2])
    ax1.plot(Total_pose[0:i, 0],Total_pose[0:i, 1], "--b", label="Robot")
    ax1.plot(Target_Total_pose[0:i, 0], Target_Total_pose[0:i, 1], "rx", label="target")
    ax1.set_title("Relative Distance[m]:" + str(Relative_distance) + ", Speed[m/s]:" + str(vr))
    ax1.axis([-15, 20, -15, 20])
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax2.plot(T[0:i], total_w_com[0:i], linewidth=2, color='C2')
    plt.pause(dt)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly. What is the input, expected output, and how does the current output differ? How do you define ax1 and ax2? If I had to guess, you have to provide to your plot function the axis object (ax1, ax2) as well, but who knows.

Comment: maybe you should use `ax1.plot()`,`ax1.arrow()` or `ax2.plot()`,`ax2.arrow()` instead of `plt.plot()`,`plt.arrow()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.